# try/catch vs describe calls inside for loop which has more performance impact?

Tags: describesobject, try-catch, sobjecttype

We have a generic method which is called in a **for loop** for each record where we try to get a value of a field using Sobject get method. Before getting the field we have to make sure that field actually exists in that sobject. Now there are two ways that we can do this. Either checking whether field exists in the Set below:

```
 Schema.SObjectType objType = ((SObject)Type.forName(objName).newInstance()).getSObjectType();
 Set<String> fieldsSet = objType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet();
```

or Using try and catch as in something like this to catch Sobjectxception whenever a field is not present on the sobject:

```
try
{
}
 catch(SObjectException ex)
{}
```

I am not sure which of them would have more implications on CPU governor limits when used inside **for loop**.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my thoughts, its not a good practice to throw exception each time when you can avoid it by checking field.

The reason behind this would be when you throw an exception, code flow has to go extra mile in catching it and and doing some additional logging mechanism which is again increased line of code characters.

As you already have a `fieldsSet`, which is a set you can easily use `contains` method to check if a field exists.